# Can we create multiple users in one login in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, users, logins

I have one database where I want 4 users in that particular database, so do I have to create 4 logins, one for each user ?

I want multiple users from one login. I tried to create a second user by using the same login but I am getting error

> The login already has an account under a different user name

Comment: This is not possible (by design). But why would you ever need more than one user for one login? Edit your post and add more information on what you're trying to solve, and maybe we can help you with better solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Authentication, then the short answer to your first question (do I have to create 4 logins, one for each user?) is, Yes. You do.

It sounds like you're looking to group individual users under a single entity.

If you are able to use Windows Authentication then you can create an Active Directory Group, let's call it GP-DatabaseUsers. Add the Windows logins as members of that group in AD, and in SQL add the group as a user and attribute the desired credentials to that group. You can still track individual login usage, but you'll be controlling security of a single entity.